Curl of current density in a wire with variable cross section
We have a wire with the shape of a cone. The cone is aligned along the z-azis. Major radius $r_M$ and minor radius $r_m$ and length $l$. An electric current $I_0$ is injected at the bottom. We could assume axisymmetry for the azimuthal angle $\phi$ around the $z$ axis, thus we say that $\mathbf{J}$ is the current density where $\mathbf{J} = j_\rho \hat{\rho} + j_z \hat{z}$ and $j_z$ could be defined as $j_z = \frac{I_0}{\pi [ R(z)] ^2}$, where $R(z)$ is the local radius of the cross section of the wire along the z-axis, and $rho$ is the radial position on the cross section of the wire.
$\mathbf{J}$ must be divergence free thus we have the following:
$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J} = 0 \Rightarrow \rho^{-1} \partial_\rho (\rho j_\rho ) + \partial_z ( j_z ) = 0 \Rightarrow j_\rho = \frac{1}{2} \rho \partial_z ( j_z )$, where we dropped the integration constant to avoid infinite values at $\rho =0$.
Now, let's calculate $\nabla \times \mathbf{J}$
$\nabla \times \mathbf{J} = (\partial_\rho j_z - \partial_z j_\rho) \hat{\phi} = - \partial_z j_\rho \hat{\phi} = - \frac{1}{2}  \frac{I_0}{\pi} \rho \partial^2_{zz} [ R(z)] ^{-2}) \hat{\phi}$, which is not necesarilly zero. The latter would mean that the electric field has a curl.
I know that Ohm's Law would require $\mathbf{J} = \sigma \mathbf{E}$, where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field and $\sigma$ is the electrical conductivity. Usually, given that this would be a conductor of uniform conductivity without current sources, it is proper to assume that $\mathbf{E} = -\nabla V$, where $V$ is a scalar potential. However, the latter would require $\nabla \times \mathbf{J} = 0$, which is not the case of this example.
Where is the inconsistency in this calculation?
Thanks in advance!

How will you do it "An electric current 0 is injected at the bottom" how is the circuit closed. ?

I think the problem is with your original assumption that $\frac{\partial J_z}{\partial \rho}=0$. Axial symmetry only demands that $\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}{J_{\rho},J_{\phi},J_z}=0$ should hold for all three components.

@trula current enters at the bottom and leaves at the top of the cone (satisfying current conservation)

@hyportnex Thanks, you are right. There's radial dependence and that allows to enforce the curl free constraint
